# Quote builder app using Rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have three models: Compartment, Option and Product, setup like this:

```
class Compartment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
    has_and_belongs_to_many :options
    ...
end

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
    has_and_belongs_to_many :compartments
    ...
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :options
    has_and_belongs_to_many :compartments
    ...
end
```

A product has many compartments and compartments has many options.

I'm not 100% sure if the models are setup correctly to do what I want. Whenever the admin creates a product, he should see all compartments and all options created, that way he can select the compartments and options available for the end user. Whenever a user logins and wants to create a quote based on a product, he should build it with the options selected by the admin. A quick example:

Admin view:

- Product A

  - Compartment A

    - Option A
    - Option B
    - Option C
  - Compartment B

    - Option A
    - Option B
    - Option C

User view:

- Product A

  - Compartment A

    - Option B
    - Option C
  - Compartment B

    - Option A

Compartments can belong to many products and the same is true for options, they can belong to many compartments.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the model configuration and most importantly how to setup the form to save/edit/create the products and quotes.

Again any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would set up map tables between the compartments and options and between the products and compartments and use

```
Class Products 
  has_many :product_compartments
  has_many :compartments, through: :product_compartments #Name of the map table
end

Class Compartment 
  has_many :product_compartments
  has_many :products, through: :product_compartments #Name of the map table
  has_many :compartment_options
  has_many :options, through: :compartment_options #Name of the map table
end

Class Option 
  has_many :compartment_options
  has_many :compartments, through: :compartment_options #Name of the map table
end
```

In your admin interface you need on form for connecting a product to a compartment could be as simple as 2 dropdowns, one with products and one with compartments.

And a similar form for compartments and options

then you can build a quote form for a product by something like

```
<% @product.compartments.each do |compartment| %>
  <%= #code rendering a checkbox for the compartment %>
  <% compartment.options.each do |option| %>
    <%= #code rendering a checkbox for the option %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can sprinkle this with javascripts hiding stuff and making it a nice UI.